# javascript nodejs trying to login to website with async

Tags: javascript, node.js

My discord bot was running smoothly and was able to login on website.
Current code:

```
login2 = async () => {
let dashboard = await superagent
  .post('https://members.iracing.com/membersite/Login?test')
  .send({ username: username, password: password, })
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

New post while login in on website looks currently like this:

```
Request URL: https://members.iracing.com/membersite/Login?test
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: 52.71.184.244:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
cache-control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self';
content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 19 Jun 2022 22:01:17 GMT
expires: Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT
location: https://members.iracing.com/membersite/member/Home.do
pragma: no-cache
server: nginx
set-cookie: AWSALB=cpwNNtOHVIQtPlT4PQCxSx6Uv+tR4Qt981YUsBIvMLcZFZ47FlY5gq5pehmPxGkwDYVrHsP5gBMFIr8d553cFEbEF2KkJRhTsPmj1+mDW/39ql8+4W43oCIUAYvj; Expires=Sun, 26 Jun 2022 22:01:16 GMT; Path=/
set-cookie: AWSALBCORS=cpwNNtOHVIQtPlT4PQCxSx6Uv+tR4Qt981YUsBIvMLcZFZ47FlY5gq5pehmPxGkwDYVrHsP5gBMFIr8d553cFEbEF2KkJRhTsPmj1+mDW/39ql8+4W43oCIUAYvj; Expires=Sun, 26 Jun 2022 22:01:16 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
set-cookie: irsso_membersv2=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: irsso_membersv2=20972393EAA1D62FF0284E5B827657145A81083C867D89E7DF998D4CC0E2CB913F999711B4490519A9F4B90E2A0812AE14EB8DF15722830C0EA6A9110030594523BAC61653B9266D71F2BE48D4BCB2DF65C0776EEA38BD57D53F0A285200B8ADF184DDDF2FBD6AEB645C388F322C1CA121E380D978371836F5B596AD4E14CECF; Domain=iracing.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: WSENV=som; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: XSESSIONID=ATC03a|Yq+cs|Yq+CN; path=/
x-maintenance-mode: false
x-via: members-fe0x-2.8.32-m-fe01
:authority: members.iracing.com
:method: POST
:path: /membersite/Login?test
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0
content-length: 98
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: JSESS_members-membersite-bosdkr02-1=7AB23279D866E95B6D0AC8F48E91561D; JSESS_members-membersite-bosdkr02-2=E60D4DFE0FAD3E25D40C94ACD432AAC1; JSESS_members-membersite-tc04-1=859AF72A2C8B4F51E390E84DB0C2F5AB; JSESS_members-membersite-bosdkr04-1=C71399B9CEAC0A5C8058DFC95711B718; JSESS_members-membersite-bosdkr05-1=BA1C48D05254AE672A23C9A8EB932011; JSESS_members-membersite-tc01-1=CD809384EEE2D64DE04DB049402CD863; JSESS_members-membersite-bosdkr04-2=FCC3A3C8EA335E892E50F3CF7983CDF0; JSESS_members-membersite-bosdkr05-2=E3A91371A2D6AEEDA250A8D0540FF508; JSESS_members-membersite-bosdkr03-2=A56A2E299FC8B89A96CBECE4E1987C52; JSESS_members-membersite-tc02-1=FCF34D0140E61E4B94C31D8F49B13F17; JSESS_members-membersite-bosdkr03-1=C2A3E1ADCED38D39044A5344A0F545A0; JSESS_members-membersite-tc03-1=20D54400B0AFAF51BC68CC7A3B336DB0; _fw_crm_v=a4cdc771-9dff-4fc8-a74c-bb845da7e86d; _ga=GA1.2.561538489.1610633062; theme=dark; _gcl_au=1.1.1778392246.1650225539; _gid=GA1.2.1954769363.1655503900; AWSALB=da+IbAmVdTahj5shSOOQ1De5NA2y0kj8rgdZ5UN7DXocSwk3gxqxnbad7dx4iWs5gjAap+ojxkZDnoSyGg/bHzzkptawOGUzfutRpHAkpY2Zq7Wvzc+H5ruhUKAT; AWSALBCORS=da+IbAmVdTahj5shSOOQ1De5NA2y0kj8rgdZ5UN7DXocSwk3gxqxnbad7dx4iWs5gjAap+ojxkZDnoSyGg/bHzzkptawOGUzfutRpHAkpY2Zq7Wvzc+H5ruhUKAT; XSESSIONID=ATC03a|Yq+cn|Yq+CN
dnt: 1
origin: https://members.iracing.com
referer: https://members.iracing.com/membersite/login.jsp
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
sec-gpc: 1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.115 Safari/537.36
```

Form data:
[form data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1jHY.png)

New website code I'm trying to log in (https://members.iracing.com/membersite/login.jsp):

```
<form method="post" name="LOGIN" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); submitHashedLoginForm();" action="/membersite/Login">
                    
                        <input class="username" tabindex="1" required="required" name="username" type="email"/>
                        <input class="password" tabindex="2" required="required" name="password" type="password"/>
                      
                        <div class="clearfix" style="width: 330px;">
                            <div class="clearfix login-w">
                                <div class="login-right clearfix">
                                
                                    <input id="submit" class="log-in" tabindex="4" type="submit" value="Log in"/>
                                
                                </div>
                                <div class="login-left clearfix">
                                    <input id="checkbox"  tabindex="3" name="AUTOLOGIN" type="checkbox" onclick="autoLoginWarning()" ><span>&nbsp;<label for="checkbox">Enable Auto Login for this Computer</label></span>
                                    <p class="tinyMargins"><a href="recoverpassword.jsp">Reset Password</a> | <a href="/membersite/SubscriptionChoices.do">Sign Up</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            <!--  <p><strong>Purchased iRacing with Steam?</strong> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:SteamLogin(this);">Log in here &raquo;</a></p> -->
                            <p><strong>To log in via Steam:</strong> <a href="/membersite/GetSteamLoginURL">Log in here &raquo;</a></p>
                            
                        </div>
                       
                        <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="utcoffset"  value="" />
                        <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="todaysdate"  value="" />
                    </form>
```

Please advise what should be changed in code, some new params maybe have to be set?
Thank you
Greg

Comment: Are you getting an error? if you get an error can you post it and please explain more about what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP error code 302 found indicates that a specific URL has been moved temporarily to a new location.

Whenever visitors, Google robots, or other search engines access the original URL, 302 redirect delivers an automatic response indicating a new address.

The 302 redirects can benefit a website on several occasions.

https://members.iracing.com/membersite/login.jsp

[image: Available forms]
As you can see there are 2 forms and the one that it is visible to users in the web it's the first one, the other should maybe be there for testing purposes.

The post request should be done to the following url:

https://members.iracing.com/membersite/membersite/Login

As you can see you need to send values for more parameters than username and password, you need to send also utcoffset and todaysdate

[image: Form inputs]

Comment: Thank you for your response. That was also my assumption regarding hidden form fields.
How can I know what values should be send for utcoffset and todaysdate?